# getting the checked nodes from tcxtreelist

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tadoquery

I have a tcxtreelist
Does anyone know how to get all the checkedNodes?

I need to go through my tcxtreelist
get a certain value from the tcxtreelist 
and write it to a string with comma delimited

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks 
Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a `cxTreeList` with 3 columns, `colChecked`, `colYear` and `colMonth`.

If you go to `colChecked` in the IDE, you can set its `Properties` property to
`CheckBox` and, at run-time, use it as a checkbox.

How to get at the `Checked` value in a given tree node is actually quite simple.
If you declare a variable `Node : TcxTreeList node`, you can assign it to any
node in the tree, as in

```
Node := cxTreeList1.Items[i];
```

Having done that, you can get at the values in the three columns of the node by
accessing the `Values` property of the node, which is a zero-based array of variants
which represent the values stored in the node and displayed in the tree.
So, you can write

```
var
  Node : TcxTreeListNode;
  Checked : Boolean;
  Year : Integer;
  Month : Integer;

begin
  Node := cxTreeList1.Items[i];
  Checked := Node.Values[0];
  Year := Node.Values[1];
  Month := Node.Values[2];
end;
```

and, of course, you can set the node's `Values` by assignments in the opposite
direction (but don't try that with the db-aware version, TcxDBTreeList, because the displayed values are determined by the contents of the fields
of the dataset connected to it).

There's no need to use the `Node` local variable, I've have only in the interests of clarity.  You could just as easily (but not so clearly) write

```
  Checked := cxTreeList1.Items[i].Values[0]
```

Here's some example code that sets up a cxTreeList with a checkbox column, populates it with rows, and generates a list of the rows which have the checkbox checked:

```
uses
  [...]cxTLData, cxDBTL, cxInplaceContainer, cxTextEdit,
  cxCheckBox, cxDropDownEdit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    cxTreeList1: TcxTreeList;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    btnGetCheckedValues: TButton;
    procedure btnGetCheckedValuesClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  protected
    colChecked : TcxTreeListColumn;
    colYear : TcxTreeListColumn;
    colMonth : TcxTreeListColumn;
  public
    procedure GetCheckedValues;
  end;

[...]
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  Year,
  Month : Integer;
  YearNode,
  MonthNode : TcxTreeListNode;
begin
  cxTreeList1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    //  Set up the cxTreeList's columns
    colChecked := cxTreeList1.CreateColumn(Nil);
    colChecked.Caption.Text := 'Checked';
    colChecked.PropertiesClassName := 'TcxCheckBoxProperties';

    colYear := cxTreeList1.CreateColumn(Nil);
    colYear.Caption.Text := 'Year';

    colMonth := cxTreeList1.CreateColumn(Nil);
    colMonth.Caption.Text := 'Month';

    //  Set up the top level (Year) and next level (Month) nodes
    for Year := 2012 to 2016 do begin
      YearNode := cxTreeList1.Root.AddChild;
      YearNode.Values[0] := Odd(Year);
      YearNode.Values[1] := Year;
      for Month := 1 to 12 do begin
        MonthNode := YearNode.AddChild;
        MonthNode.Values[0] := False;
        MonthNode.Values[1] := Year;
        MonthNode.Values[2] := Month;
      end;
    end;

  finally
    cxTreeList1.FullExpand;
    cxTreeList1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetCheckedValues;
var
  i : Integer;
  Node : TcxTreeListNode;
  S : String;
begin
  for i := 0 to cxTreeList1.Count - 1 do begin
    Node := cxTreeList1.Items[i];
    if Node.Values[0] then begin
      S := Format('Item: %d, col0: %s col1: %s col2: %s', [i, Node.Values[0], Node.Values[1], Node.Values[2]]);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnGetCheckedValuesClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetCheckedValues;
end;
```

Comment: I have a tcxTreeList with 3 columns the first column has property of checkgroup enabled, It will contain Checkbox with Text and 2nd column contains Key of the First root node and third column contains the keys of all child nodes under the root node. how can i get the key of root node whether it is checked or not and keys of all checked child nodes into 2 variables.

Comment: You should post a new q to ask this question.

Comment: Here is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991592/delphi-cxtreelist-looping-through-nodes